# Why do I get "-eq: unary operator expected false"?

Tags: shell-script

I get

```
$ ./5_divisible_by_1_to_10.sh 
./5_divisible_by_1_to_10.sh: line 16: [: -eq: unary operator expected
 false
true
```

for:

```
divisible_by () {
  under_test=$1
  from=2
  to=4
  divisible=0
  for ((check=from; check<=to; check++)) {
    if [ $(($under_test % $check)) -ne 0 ]; then
      divisible=1
    fi  
  }
  return $divisible
}

divider=10
x= divisible_by "$divider"
if [ $x -eq 0 ]; then  # <--- Line 16
  echo "$x true"
else
  echo "$x false"
fi
divider=12
if divisible_by $divider; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

The second call for 12 works ok but the first call using 10, where I am trying to display the result gives the error.

Adding quotes around `$x`, i.e `"$x"` gives a different error:

```
$ ./5_divisible_by_1_to_10.sh 
./5_divisible_by_1_to_10.sh: line 16: [: : integer expression expected
 false
true
```

Comment: again - `$x` is empty. The syntax for `test` is `[ num -op num ]` and you feed it `[ -op num ]`. That won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
if [ $x -eq 0 ]
```

`x` is empty because the line

```
x= divisible_by "$divider"
```

is wrong: It calls `divisible_by` with the empty environment variable `x` but doesn't even try to set `x` in the shell environment. You need:

```
divisible_by "$divider"
x=$?
```

And you should always quote your variables.